# React typescript - split array into alphabetical groups

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I have a string array with many (100+) words, I have sorted the array in alphabetical order, but I want group or split the array into hash array `hashMap<String(Alphabet), List<String>>`, so I can show it in this style:

[image: Desired Result]

```
const stringArray = [
    "Apple",
    "animal",
    "Apart",
    "ball",
    "backpack",
    "ballers",
    "bingo",
    "cars",
    "Careful",
    "Coach"
  ]

 {stringArray && stringArray?.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a < b) { return -1; }
            if (a > b) { return 1; }
            return 0;
          }).map(word => (
            <hr><hr />
            <p>{word}</p>
          ))}
```

Comment: How does your array looks like? Add it in the question itself. Atleast add partial array.

Comment: Added a quick example of an array

Comment: can you show the result of what you have tried so we can help debug?

Comment: well the result just lists each words in alphabetical order EX: animal apart apple backpack etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or using plain object as:

**Live Demo using Map**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**Live Demo using object**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
const arr = [
  "Apple",
  "animal",
  "Apart",
  "ball",
  "backpack",
  "ballers",
  "bingo",
  "cars",
  "Careful",
  "Coach",
];
const getFilteredArr = (arr) => {
  const map = new Map();
  arr
    .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
    .forEach((str) =>
      !map.has(str[0].toLowerCase())
        ? map.set(str[0].toLowerCase(), [str])
        : map.get(str[0].toLowerCase()).push(str)
    );
  return [...map];
};
const newArray = getFilteredArr(arr);

return (
  <>
    <div>
      {newArray.map(([key, values]) => {
        return (
          <div key={key}>
            <h1>{key}</h1>
            {values.map((str) => (
              <p key={str}>{str}</p>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  </>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the live demo, is it possible to do it without using map? I mean by maybe just checking the first character since its already sorted? Or is this the most elegant way of doing it

Comment: There are many ways to do this, This is just one of them. You can also use plain object also.

Comment: You just have to separate words that starts with same character, for that you can use any algo. But I find using Map is the easiest and simplest and efficient also.

Comment: Btw Im getting this error for `return [...map]`ErrorMsg `Type 'IterableIterator<[any, any]>' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.`

Comment: If this is not working then you can use another demo created for you in the answer. Have a look

Comment: Im getting `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`for line 35 `{values.map((str) => (`

Comment: Take a look at the codesandbox link that I've added. You might have done something wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a custom sort function, JS sorts alphabetically by default.  So first sort your words:

```
words.sort();
```

Then iterate over them and add them to a 2nd map that is keyed off of the starting letter:

```
const letterMap = new Map();
words.forEach(word => {
  const letter = word[0].toUpperCase();
  if (!letterMap.has(letter)) letterMap.set(letter, []);
  letterMap.get(letter).push(word);
});
```

Now `letterMap` looks like: `{'A': ['Apple', 'Animal', ...], 'B': [...]}`, and you can iterate over *this* using `letterMap.entries`:

```
const HTML = [...letterMap.entries()].forEach((letter, words) => {
  return `${letter}<hr><hr />` +
         `<p>${words.join(' ')}</p>`;
})
```